# Are periods the horizontal numbers on the periodic table and groups the vertical numbers?

Tags: nomenclature, periodic-trends, periodic-table

I am writing this post so that I can ensure for my upcoming SUC3U0 (Chemistry, Grade 11) course test of nomenclature is correct. It's a Review of my Grade 10 General Science Course.

My teacher stated something odd:
She said on the periodic table, the vertical numbers are called Groups and horizontal are periods. Now from my previous understanding, its supposed to be the other way around. I then showed her a periodic table from ChemLabs and Wikipedia disapproving her point and affirming my point of the groups being horizontal and periods being vertical but she says I am wrong and the sites are wrong.

Below is a picture from Wikipedia that I annotated. It shows in blue what my teacher says (Periods at top, Groups Vertically); and we can see what is stated by the creator of the diagram, which again contradicts this point.

Picture below:
[image: Picture in Question!!]

This is also posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/comments/16j0yi3/my_teacher_states_that_periods_are_the_horizantal/ for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First understand the concept of a period and then it make more sense why a period is a period and why a group is a group. In mathematics, any function which repeats itself after a certain period (say, time period), it is called a periodic function. I am sure you are familiar with sine and cosine functions. They repeat themselves after every 2$\pi$. A clock repeats itself twice in 24 hours. In the same way, the way elements are arranged in *rows* repeat their properties. Now also note that most Western languages start reading from left to right. So start with atomic numbers, 1,2,3, and so on from left to right. Hydrogen, to helium (first two gases), then Li, Be, B, C, N, O, F, Ne, stop here and note that the next element is Na, which is very similar to Li in chemical properties. So the chemical properties are repeating themselves, after a certain number of elements. This is why the set {Li, Be, B, C, N, O, F, Ne} forms a so called "period". Repeat the same exercise, till you reach K.

Now, Li, Na, K, Rb have very similar properties, both chemical and physical. This is why it is natural to call them a group. Look at the periodic table, this set is vertical.

In short, horizontal rows = periods;
vertical columns = groups.

Answer (score 0):

> My teacher states that periods are the horizontal numbers on the perioidc table and groups are the vertical

Groups and periods refer to sets of elements, and these sets have numeric labels (and sometimes names).

#### Groups

Here are two examples of groups. Group 17 (the halogens, boxed in magenta) comprises six elements, while group 8 (sometimes called the iron group, boxed in purple) comprises four elements. In the periodic table, elements in a given group form a column (top to bottom, or vertical).
[image]

#### Periods

Here are two examples of periods. The second period (boxed in magenta) comprises 8 elements, and the sixth period (boxed in purple) comprises 32 elements. In the periodic table, elements in a given period form a row (left to right, or horizontal). Period 6 appears in two rows in the short-form periodic table shown below, but is in a single row in the [long-form periodic](https://www.sciencegeek.net/tables/LongTable2000.png) table.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As I have written in comments in the very beginning,
there are 18 vertical groups and 7 horizontal periods.

You may have noticed that  e.g. on Excel spreadsheets,

- horizontal rows of cells are numbered in a vertical column on the left,
- vertical columns of cells are numbered in a horizontal raw the top.

It is similar for the Periodic table of elements. That could be the primary source of misunderstanding on either or both sides, if one talks about objects (groups, periods) and the other about object numbering.

The best would be probably to focus, what a group and a period means generally, not being related to the Periodic table nor chemistry at all. Then you can imply what are groups and what are periods in the Periodic table of elements and you would not have to rely on what you are told.

That is better than to memorize what is what, without understanding what all are talking about.

Imagine this fruit arrangement on a table as a 6x6 set:

| Positions | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-smallest | apple | pear | orange | banana | grapes | mango |
| 2 | apple | pear | orange | banana | grapes | mango |
| 3 | apple | pear | orange | banana | grapes | mango |
| 4 | apple | pear | orange | banana | grapes | mango |
| 5 | apple | pear | orange | banana | grapes | mango |
| 6-biggest | apple | pear | orange | banana | grapes | mango |

Groups are collections of members that are similar, or have some common properties.

- In our fruit collection, 6 apples make the apple group, 6 pears make a pear group, etc. Each group is sorted by size, the smallest first.
- In the element case, H, Li, Na, K, Rb, Cs, Fr make the group of alkali metals, having similar chemical properties. H is an outlier, but that is not important now.
- Similarly Be, Mg, Ca, Sr, Ba, Ra have similar properties, making the alkali earth metal group.
- We can check other groups, column per column to the far right, where He, Ne, Ar, Kr, Xe, Rn have similar properties too, making the group of noble gases.

If members of a collection are arranged in a pattern that is regularly repeated, a period is one such a repetition.

- The line apple to mango consists of different kinds of fruits, but the fruit pattern repeats every 6 fruits. The set apple-to-mango makes a 6 member period, being followed by the repeated pattern of another period apple-to-mango, that is very similar to the prior one.
- At the Periodic table, each row of the table is a period, starting with alkali metal, reacting with water, progressively going through elements loosing metallic properties and ending with a noble gas, that is usually chemically inert.
- You can see periods get longer every second period, as more groups are being added. But initial and ending patterns of the periods remain.

You can see then yourself on the Periodic table that there is 7 periods arranged in rows and 18 groups, arranged in columns.